# Time complexity of a convergent series

Tags: time-complexity

I wanted to ask a simple question:
Assume I have a function whose time complexity is given by the following function:
$T(n)=\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+...+\frac{1}{n^2}$.
Would it be correct to say that the time complexity of the function is $Θ(1)$ because $T(n)$ is represented by a convergent series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every sufficiently large $n$ (here $n \ge 1$ suffices), $T(n)$ is both lower bounded by a positive constant (e.g., $1$) and upper bounded by another positive constant  (e.g., $\pi^2/6$). Therefore it is correct to say that $T(n) = \Theta(1)$.